# Python script, .py or text file, output to tinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, pycharm, visualization

I have created a tkinter gui with buttons and upon pressing them, they execute a .py file in the terminal. The .py file uses a text file in the code to generate a graph so it is not always a fixated image. so every time the button is selected, and a new graph image is generated, it needs to appear on the gui.

Is there a way of getting the output to the gui instead of displaying it in the terminal?

my code:

```
def visualise():
    with open(example.png, "w") as output:
        command = ("python graph.py")
        p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=output, stderr=output, shell=True)

buttongraph = Tkinter.Button(self, text="generate graph", command=visualise)
buttongraph.pack()
```

Comment: What have you tried in terms of changing output from terminal to GUI?

Comment: @pstatix honestly I have tried so many things. I have used subprocess to declare the command and called it to the tkinter button, "pull data" to read the .py file and declared it in a different frame on the gui to put as an output but no luck. It did spit something out but it was just the text and not in an image format.

Comment: When your terminal is showing the image, its just using ASCII characters to show this graph correct? Its not displaying a JPEG/PNG/GIF/etc...?

Comment: the terminal is showing the JPEG but on the gui it is not, it is just the text  in a paragraph @pstatix

Comment: What terminal are you using? The image isnt _in_ the console is it? It opens an image viewer for you?

Comment: Default Windows console cannot show images, unless you've added other things to it or use a different console. Plus I have no idea what is in `python graph.py`

Comment: Do you by any chance name like a `jupiter notebook` as terminal? In any case please put a complete mwe example so we can help you better.

Comment: @pstatix i am currently using pycharm on my MacBook. the image opens in the console/terminal next to the code. If i use terminal on a linux OS, it opens in an image viewer. However, i am trying to get this output to show onto the gui. Hope i make sense...